# How to extract the <title> value

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

JS is not my main skill, hope someone can help. I am trying to make a GTM variable to extract . Problem is that I cant use class="rg-trailer-icon" as a class name because it changes based on the truck type that is viewed (trailer, truck, etc)

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Are there any other titled SVGs on the page? If not you could use `querySelector('svg title')` Otherwise maybe `.row.rg-vec-make-model title`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the title. You just have to scramble through.

```js
t = document.querySelector('#scheduleContainer svg title').innerHTML
console.log(t)
```

```html
<div id="scheduleContainer">
  <div>
    <div>
      <svg>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <path>
          </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you All! this did the job : document.querySelector('#scheduleContainer svg title').innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, using `document.title` should be enough

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a page title :)

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't notice.
maybe jquery would help in that case... anyways I'm glad someone already helped :D